# Content is cropped on mobile Firefox; can't scroll or zoom it into view

Tags: bug, design, mobile-web

To reproduce, open for example [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/118183/13921) on latest (44.0) Firefox on Android (using the default mobile view). The text in this answer goes all the way right to the edge of the screen. If I scroll right there's a ~1cm margin which is completely blank, hiding large parts of the text and almost all of the image.

I've seen this many times, and **the only workaround seems to be requesting the desktop version of the site.** Neither scrolling nor zooming reveals more of the content. Rotating the screen into landscape mode reveals more content, but it's still cropped.

This is speculation, but the problem seems to arise whenever there's a fixed width item (such as an image) which is wider than the screen.

Comment: Are you using the mobile view or desktop view?

Comment: @Oded happens to me when using the mobile view. The same happens in the android app, too.